# Android SDK Download doesn't start

Tags: android, download, sdk

I'm trying to download the Android SDK from Android Developers Page but it only takes me to installation steps and the download never starts.

I tried using Chrome and Firefox on Linux and Windows and the download doesnt work.

Have any idea of where could be the problem? or maybe another way or page to download it (I need it for Ubuntu 14.04).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I know you probably have already tried this.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

If you click on the SDK it will take you to a license page. Try turning off an ad-blocker if you have one on.

If you are unable to get just the SDK, you can try to get the full Android Studio suite and download the SDK through that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah i went there and it doesnt work neither, does it work for you? Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, it is working for me. I'm using Google Chrome. Perhaps it is your browser? And I know it's obvious, but worth mentioning make sure you check the box that says, "I agree".

Comment: Yeah, it could be an IP problem cuz i've tried with firefox and chrome but none will work, also i've tried with Ubuntu and have the same result, and yeah i've checked terms and conditions.

Comment: This worked for me. I "paused" AdBlock, and the download worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go here: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.2.2.0/android-studio-bundle-141.1980579-windows.exe

Click the big green button!

Accept Terms.

Profit?

Comment: I already tried that and it doesnt work, i accep terms but it takes me to installation steps

Comment: @SebastianHernandez here ya go, direct link buddy

Comment: It doesnt work, this is the error that appears in the console: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: hmm try in console `wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.2.2.0/android-studio-bundle-141.1980579-windows.exe`

Comment: It sends the HTTP Call but keeps waiting for the answer... and the answer never comes

Comment: Well seems like something's wrong with the router or the isp! Ty resetting the router & contacting the ISP, that's all I can do for you :(

Comment: this is for windows. The question was about ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into this on the main site. There is a redirect that happens within like, 1.5 seconds, so if you're using IE and it's asking you to "save as" it will disappear unless you hurry up and click the button. I have to race this every time on a fresh computer, before I get other browsers. I reported this bug half a year ago and it is still around.

Answer (score 0):

this is the link for the latest version 
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.3.3.0/android-studio-bundle-162.4069837-windows.exe

or on the download page when you  agree the terms than right click on the blue download button and copy link address to IMD and it will start downloading ,